# How to retrieve data from multiple nodes with multiple childs from firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to show data of recent bookings of a user from firebase database in a  recycler view. I have tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
final String id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Bookings");
    DatabaseReference dateRef = rootRef.child(id);

    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String Ftour =  ds.child("Tour").getValue(String.class);
                    String FPeople = ds.child("TotalPeople").getValue(String.class);
                    String FPrice =  ds.child("TotalPrice").getValue(String.class);
                   Log.d("TAG", Ftour + " / " + FPeople + " / "+ FPrice);

                    listD.add(new RHolder(Ftour,FPeople,FPrice));
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
    dateRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

And my database is this:

[image: Database Image Here]

I want **TotalPeople** **TotalPrice** and **Tour** to be shown in Recyclerview

Comment: why didn't it work? are you getting an runtime error or is the output wrong?

Comment: when i open it, it goes back to previously open page automatically

Comment: I think it not related to firebase. It look working for me. Please check it in your code maybe you have call 'finish()' somewhere in adapter or activity/fragment that related to this screen

Comment: now it is not closing automatically but it doesn't shows any data into recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell your code is not handling the `Recent` level that you have in your JSON. If that is indeed the cause of the problem you describe, you can fix it with:

```
dateRef.child("Recent").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```